# Pandas duplicated indexes still shows correct elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'score1' : pandas.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']), 'score2' : pandas.Series(['b', 'a', 'k', 'n', 'c'])})
```

Output:

```
  score1  score2
0   a       b
1   b       a
2   c       k
3   d       n
4   e       c
```

I then split the `score1` and `score2` columns and concatenate them together:

```
In (283): frame1 = test[['score1']]
          frame2 = test[['score2']]
          frame2.rename(columns={'score2': 'score1'}, inplace=True)

          test = pandas.concat([frame1, frame2])

          test

Out[283]:   
   score1
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
0   b
1   a
2   k
3   n
4   c
```

**Notice the duplicate indexes.** Now if I do a `groupby` and then retrieve a group using `get_group()`, pandas is still able to retrieve the elements with the correct index, even though the indexes are duplicated!

```
In (283): groups = test.groupby('score1')

          groups.get_group('a') # Get group with key a

Out[283]: 
    score1
0   a
1   a

In (283): groups.get_group('b') # Get group with key b

Out[283]: 
    score1
1   b
0   b
```

I understand that pandas uses an inverted index data structure for storing the groups, which looks like this:

```
In (284): groups.groups

Out[284]: {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [1, 0], 'c': [2, 4], 'd': [3], 'e': [4], 'k': [2], 'n': [3]}
```

If both `a` and `b` are stored at index `0`, how does pandas show me the elements correctly when I do `get_group()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is into the internals (i.e., don't rely on this API!) but the way it works now is that there is a `Grouping` object which stores the groups in terms of positions, rather than index labels.

```
In [25]: gb = test.groupby('score1')

In [26]: gb.grouper
Out[26]: <pandas.core.groupby.BaseGrouper at 0x4162b70>

In [27]: gb.grouper.groupings
Out[27]: [Grouping(score1)]

In [28]: gb.grouper.groupings[0]
Out[28]: Grouping(score1)

In [29]: gb.grouper.groupings[0].indices
Out[29]: 
{'a': array([0, 6], dtype=int64),
 'b': array([1, 5], dtype=int64),
 'c': array([2, 9], dtype=int64),
 'd': array([3], dtype=int64),
 'e': array([4], dtype=int64),
 'k': array([7], dtype=int64),
 'n': array([8], dtype=int64)}
```

See here for where it's actually implemented.
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2091

Comment: I did suspect that this was the case. Thank for clearing it up!